# Optimization: One time vs Staging

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I ran into a situation with two options:

1. Use a single query with a cost of ~0.07

   ```
   INSERT INTO @vals
   SELECT ...
     FROM ...
     JOIN ... 
     JOIN ...
    WHERE a.col = 1 OR b.col IS NOT NULL
   ```
2. Use two queries to get the same result -- the first cost ~0.05, the second cost ~0.3

   ```
   INSERT INTO @temp
   SELECT ...
     FROM ...
     JOIN ...

   INSERT INTO @vals
   SELECT ...
     FROM @temp
     JOIN ...
    WHERE a.col = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ...
     FROM @temp
     JOIN ...
     JOIN ...
    WHERE b.col IS NOT NULL
   ```

I chose the first option - single query, so less concern of mutating data between queries and less overall cost.  Was this the prudent choice?

This was for an operation that originally took ~5+ minutes, timing out in our application.  The re-write got that down to 1.5 minutes consistently, using table variables with unique clustered indexes.

Comment: Is the query an update or a read? Write queries contain protection against 'mutating data' (mostly in form of [haloween protection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2008/02/27/halloween-protection.aspx)) but read queries contain weaker protection semantics (derived from isolation level).

Comment: @RemusRusanu: IMO write queries may provide complete protection against 'mutating data', but we cannot assume it is always the case - there are many examples proving otherwise. What do you think?

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov: most of those cases are examples of 'optimizing one step beyond correctness'...

Comment: @RemusRusanu: The ultimate operation is an update.  The query options I posted were for populating table variables to get the details for the update (adjacency model).

Comment: The estimated subtree costs shown in SQL Server execution plans aren't always that useful for comparing queries. Particularly where table variables are concerned due to the one row assumption. Can you show the (possibly simplified) queries?

Comment: "Was this the prudent choice?" In what regard (atomicity/performance/concurrency/etc)? Which property is most important for this operation? Also, 1.5 minutes is still a really long time for an OLTP operation. Could you provide more detail on what you're doing?

Comment: @MartinSmith: See update

Answer (score 3):

The difference between one and two queries may not be as large as you'd think. For example, compare this query:

```
declare @t table (id int)
insert into @t select id from Table1 where col1 = 7
update Table1 set col2 = 8 where id in (select id from @t)
```

to this query:

```
update Table1 set col2 = 8 where id in (select id from Table1 where col1 = 7)
```

For the second query, SQL Server could run the subquery first, and store the result in a  temporary table.  If it did that, that would be the EXACT SAME way it executes the first query!

So the effect of splitting a query in two is that it limits the query optimizer's choice.  The first query demands that the subquery is executed before the updates.  The second query leaves the optimizer free to fetch one row, then update the table, and then fetch the next row.

Now when you upgrade the hardware, SQL Server version, or if the database changes, you would ideally re-verify that your limitation is in fact beneficial. That's kind of expensive.

So I would prefer not split the query, or enforce a query plan, unless the expense is offset by a considerable advantage.  Going from 0.07 to 0.3 seconds doesn't look like a big difference to me, unless the query is run more than once every minute or so.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I'm using table variables for the indexing -- indexed views, with better read for the performance hit of populating the index.  I looked at using a CTE for the operation, but a CTE is just syntactic sugar.  The amount of time the operation takes is important -- it's timing out in the app.

Comment: @Andomar : I think there is a big difference in 2 approaches you mentioned. The second one guarantees to be atomic, the first one as it is may update records that were changed between `insert` and `update` or skip new records that would satisfy condition `col1 =7`.

Comment: @a1ex07 - Yep, and to fix that first query to behave atomically you'd need to set your isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE` or `REPEATABLE READ`. (In this case [`REPEATABLE READ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) is OK because after the initial `INSERT` runs, new data can only enter the range `WHERE col1 = 7` but not leave it.)

Comment: @a1ex07, NickChammas: The second one is not "guaranteed to be atomic".  Changes are possible between the select and the update for both queries.

Comment: @Andomar: Not sure I understand you. Single statement is supposed to be atomic, isn't it? Subquery cannot return row that didn't exist at the beginning of its execution. `UPDATE` should cause `U` and then `X` locks on the records. Unless I'm missing something obvious (if you think it's the case, I'd really appreciate if you point me to the right direction), the second query should be atomic (taking into account that we select and update the same table)

Comment: @a1ex07: The second statement can scan the table and release it's locks, and then the update part can make changes.  That's even more obvious if the read part acts on just one index.  It's relatively easy to prove with a `while` loop in two SSMS windows. (Btw, we're both misusing atomic, which is supposed to mean the query succeeds or fails entirely.)

Comment: Ok, I see your point, and it makes sense. Also, I agree about misusing word 'atomic' in this context. But I still think that 1query can potentially produce more consistent results.

Comment: Don't know if you're right about the locking behavior in the second query, but yes, we should be talking about the query looking at an *isolated* view of the data, rather than query atomicity. Frankly, in this particular example, I can't see for either query how it would be harmful if rows `WHERE col1 = 7` were added or removed mid-operation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one query should almost always behave better. The overall performance problems may be related to the fact that SQLServer blocks readers until write transaction completes. Fortunately, it can be changed with setting db option `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON`. I'm not 100% sure if it's the culprit in your case, but I personally saw a great performance improvement because of setting this option.